# SetInterval function in javascript is taking longer time to execute

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Set Interval function of Javascript is been used for closing the popup after 9 minutes in my react Application. There are 15 popup in my entire application so they are in different components.It works fine on local machine each popup is closed after 9 minute, but it takes 15 minutes on DEV environment

```
timeOut() {
        this.OGintervalId  = setInterval(() => {
            var totalTime = getStorage("timeout");
            var logoutTime = getStorage("expirationConfiguration");
            if (totalTime === logoutTime) {
                var url = window.location.href.split("/").pop();
                if (url === "AppointmentType" || url === "") {
                    var PopupDisplay = $("#appoitmenttypemodal").css("display");
                    var restrcitDisplay = $("#restrictAppnt").css("display"); 
                    if (PopupDisplay === "block") {
                        clearInterval(this.OGintervalId);
                        document.getElementById("closeAppntPopup").click();
                    } else if (restrcitDisplay === "block") {
                        clearInterval(this.OGintervalId);
                        document.getElementById("closeThisPopup").click();
                    }
                }
            }
        }, 1000);
    };
```

method is called inside the popup code

```
<div className="modal-dialog">
                <div className="modal-content">
                    {this.timeOut()}
                    <div className="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" className="close" id="modalclosenopatientfound" onClick={this.props.enableLocationStep} data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 className="modal-title" ><Translate>Message</Translate></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div className="modal-body">
                         hey
                                      </div>
                    <div className="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" className="dismissbuttons" data-dismiss="modal">
                        <Translate>Ok</Translate></button>
                        <button data-dismiss="modal" id="closeThisPopup" style={{ opacity: 0, width: 0, height: 0 }}></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

There is a hidden button on popup which gets clicked for closing the popup ie closeThisPopup

Comment: FWIW, this looks really dodgy: `if (totalTime === logoutTime) {` I'd definitely use `>=`.

Comment: you'll want to compare timestamps (`new Date().getTime()`) instead of durations.

Comment: var totalTime = getStorage("timeout");
var logoutTime = getStorage("expirationConfiguration"); comes from server  and my time for 1 session is 10 min so when 9 min get reduce to 1 min , i should close the popup and show logout popup

Comment: This is a bad way of doing that all around I'm sorry to say. Each re-render will start  over the interval (which is probably what causes the issue), and showing/hiding elements by calling jQuery's `css()` on them is decisively not the React way of handling this. Whether the modal is open or not is supposed to be part of the app state, for instance.

Comment: Here's example code for a modal that will auto-close after five seconds: https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-wing-s40rs?file=/src/App.js